# Android: How to show the action bar on top?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I was following [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html) tutorial to add an `ActionBar` for my app.

I create a blank new project in Android studio by default and the **android version** is **11**. When I launch my app, the `ActionBar` is not showing on top of my app but is hidden in the bottom; It shows up when I hit the menu `button` of my phone.

I am wondering if it is an expect behavior? What should I do to make it shows on the top?

[image]

Comment: good article to know more..http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [**ActionBarSherlock**](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library and it'll provide backword compatibility for older versions.

Comment: It is really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/index.html) , this will help you:

[this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/) is also good.